# Prints have over extrusion only during diagonals

Tags: extrusion, 3d-printerworks

So I have printed multiple benchies with various slicer settings. I have also made sure my bed is leveled well.

But no matter what I do, I get these over extrusion whenever my nozzle is moving in diagonals (left-right). It's always this same angle where it goes wrong.

Has anyone else who has faced this and has figured out know what the issue can be? I'm new to 3D printing so the help would be very much appreciated.

[image: Picture of sample extrusion problem]

Comment: Please tell us what printer, what slicer, and what firmware you are using. Your slicer settings will help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the X-axis belt was super loose, figured it after someone pointed it out on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/nwpxux/prints_have_over_extrusion_only_during_diagonals/h1akrax?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

> swordfish45
>
> You have an extremely loose x belt. That's the root cause of all your problems I can see in these pics.